# How to have Parent (relative) expand according to a Child (absolute) div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I understand similar questions have been asked multiple time, I've tried their solutions tailored to my code but none of them seem to work. My website has a header with a div inside of it containing a Wordpress Contact Form 7 form. The whole site is responsive, other than the Contact form div which stays it's height (not fixed) and doesn't decrease in height - only width. Below is the code. `#imgDiv` is the parent and `#property-search` is the child div. `#property-search` is the div that only decreases in width and not height.

```css
#imgDiv { position: relative; width: 100%; overflow: auto;}
#imgDiv img { width: 100%; }
#property-search { position: absolute;top: 0; margin-left: 450px; min-width: 18%; background-color: rgba(23, 81, 61, 0.5); overflow: auto; margin-right: 450px;}
```

EDIT: I understand that positioning absolute will result in the child div not changing in height relative to it's parent. Hence, I'm looking for a way round this, rather than to be educated on the use of absolute and relative position. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: You understand that absolutely positioned elements ***cannot*** affect relative parents but you're still asking for a workaround....there isn't one other than not using `position:absolute`.

Comment: you will need javascript if you want to keep the child absolute, but without further context - ie a little html I can't really comment on a better workaround

Comment: By the looks of your css though, you are putting text on top of an image so why not just make the image a background image on the imgDiv and then make your property search relative?

Comment: Thanks Pete. That's exactly what I did just after posting the question. It worked! Thanks.

Comment: Hahaha, always happens when you post a question, you often figure it out straight away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the need for the absolute positioning is for but if it only to put your text on top of your image, why not just make your image a background-image?

```css
#imgDiv {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background:url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000/city/1/) top center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
#property-search {
  margin-left: 450px;
  min-width: 18%;
  background-color: rgba(23, 81, 61, 0.5);
  overflow: auto;
  margin-right: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div id="imgDiv">
  <div id="property-search">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vulputate vehicula nisl, vel cursus dolor euismod ut. Praesent ullamcorper pellentesque tellus at sagittis. Etiam rutrum finibus leo at ornare. Praesent fringilla diam at sem egestas, eu dictum urna ullamcorper. Proin ultrices massa sem, vitae convallis nisi rutrum vel. Morbi lobortis metus in arcu consequat, ac sodales mauris interdum. Duis sit amet imperdiet lorem. Aliquam libero odio, vehicula mattis lobortis eu, sagittis eu quam.

Nullam cursus eleifend eros sit amet egestas. Donec vulputate pulvinar neque in rhoncus. Donec ut nibh ac ligula tristique mollis a a quam. Integer iaculis vitae sapien vitae lacinia. Praesent orci urna, maximus non purus vitae, auctor venenatis magna. Duis ante nisi, accumsan id vulputate vitae, efficitur eget turpis. Curabitur et sem pulvinar, posuere magna in, luctus risus. Phasellus bibendum nibh eu ligula ultricies elementum. Vivamus mattis orci mauris, at mattis mauris suscipit in. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vel lobortis augue. Quisque eu lectus a lacus congue commodo. Maecenas non euismod libero. Proin volutpat lacus vitae venenatis aliquam. Phasellus sed ex sit amet nibh sollicitudin vulputate ut nec ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```